# Is "in exchange for" valid at both the beginning and end of "What did you give him money in exchange for?"?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, word-order, questions, prepositional-phrases

I would like to learn if these kinds of questions are possible and correct in English. I think they are but I'm not sure.

> 1. What did you give him the money in exchange for?
> 2. In exchange for what did you give him the money?
> 3. What are you writing to me in relation to?
> 4. In relation to what are you writing to me?

Comment: For the first two I would ask "What did you pay him for?" In the second two I would ask "Why are you writing to me?

Answer (score -1):

All those questions are acceptable.

> What did you give him the money in exchange for?

There is a "rule" that you should not end a sentence with a preposition, but this "rule" is broken very very often. The above question would be common in everyday speech, but probably not legal documents or an official address to the United Nations or something. You should be aware of the rule, and break it only when you have a good stylistic reason.

> In exchange for what did you give him the money?

This is okay as well, and the most correct in a strict sense. You could also use:

> For what did you give him the money in exchange?

But this is a little convoluted and sounds like you're trying too hard. It's still grammatically correct.

As Weather Vane says, all of the options are on the wordy side, and you could make them sound more natural by making them more direct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your widely explained answer. I'm okay for all of your comments except for the part "For what did you give him the money in exchange?". I think this sentence is grammatical, as you have already signified, although it can be understood and answered in many ways that can change the meaning a little bit. One can answer the question like "For you, I gave him the money in exchange" OR "I gave him the money for my wedding in exchange". So, what the question exactly asks is not certain in your 3rd example, I think.